# Replace content of each HTML controls javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I'm trying again to replace each text content of each control in a page using javascript and jquery.

I need to search in each text content (WITHOUT MODIFING TAGS, ONLY THE TEXT) any word and replace it with another any word.

One try is:

```
jQuery.fn.replaceEachOne = function (objective, rep) {
   this.each( function(){ 
                //$(this).html( $(this).html().replace( new RegExp('(\\s'+objective+'\\s(?![[\\w\\s?&.\\/;#~%"=-]*>]))', "ig"), rep) );
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace( new RegExp('('+objective+'(?![[\\w\\s?&.\\/;#~%"=-]*>]))', "ig"), rep) );
            }
        );
}
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$.fn.replaceEachOne = function(search, replace) {
    this.contents().each(function(){
        if (this.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            $(this).replaceEachOne(search, replace);
        } else if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(search, replace);
        }
    });
};
```

This does the replacement on text nodes directly, rather than modifying the HTML of an entire element.  Note that it is case-sensitive.  You'd need to change the call to `replace` to use a regular expression if you want a case-insensitive search.

Comment: Thats work, but I have to add a new control to the finded text, I mean add: <label Color="..."> Finded Text </label> 
and if I do it in that way the browser dont recognize it as control, only as text, I mean, it apears textually <label Color="..."> Finded Text </label> not a Cool label with a diferent color... :(

help!!

Comment: @Daniel G.R. Sounds like you need [a highlighting plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would start by something like this:

```
jQuery.fn.replaceEachOne = function(objective, rep) {
    var html = jQuery(this).html();
    var simpleRegexp = new RegExp(objective, "gi");
    var regexp = new RegExp(">[^><]*?"+objective+"[^><]*?<","gi");
    html = html.replace(regexp, function(match) {
        return match.replace(simpleRegexp, rep);
    });
    jQuery(this).html(html);
}
```

That code finds the matching text in body html code beetween `'>'` and `'<'` characters and then replaces matched text.

Of course this is simple solution and it will replace text also in `<script>` or `<style>` blocks. By I think it is a good idea to start with.

Comment: But the problem is that I dont want to add content into the <> I need to add content in    <> HERE </>

Comment: I've wrote "beetween '>' and '<'", not "beetween '<' and '>'". The order is important.

Comment: Edit info: I've replaced "body" by this.

Comment: I've tried that: jQuery("body").replaceEachOne("jquery", "<label style='color:red'>jquery</label>"); on jQuery.org and it chenged color of all jquery occurences on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Finally...

```
jQuery.fn.replaceEachOne = function (objective, reposition) {
    this.contents().each(function(){
        if (this.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            $(this).replaceEachOne(objective, reposition);
        } else if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            var label = document.createElement("label");
            label.innerHTML = this.nodeValue.replace(objective, reposition);
            this.parentNode.insertBefore(label, this);
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        }
    }); 
}
```